# Nginx and Solr server on port 8983 but can't access Admin area

Tags: apache, nginx, solr

Im running Nginx and I just installed solr.

Service status reports everythign is ok...

```
sudo service solr statusroot@closer:~# sudo service solr status
● solr.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2018-07-14 18:21:14 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2549 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/solr stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2699 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 14 18:21:08 closer solr[2699]:  If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
Jul 14 18:21:08 closer solr[2699]: *** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 3896.
Jul 14 18:21:08 closer solr[2699]:  It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption.
Jul 14 18:21:08 closer solr[2699]:  If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
Jul 14 18:21:08 closer solr[2699]: Warning: Available entropy is low. As a result, use of the UUIDField, SSL, or any other features that require
Jul 14 18:21:08 closer solr[2699]: RNG might not work properly. To check for the amount of available entropy, use 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entr
Jul 14 18:21:14 closer solr[2699]: [194B blob data]
Jul 14 18:21:14 closer solr[2699]: Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=2751). Happy searching!
Jul 14 18:21:14 closer solr[2699]: [14B blob data]
Jul 14 18:21:14 closer systemd[1]: Started LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service.
```

but if I try to go to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr

I can't access the page...why?

do i have to ufw port 8983?
do i have to start apache?
else?

Comment: Are you testing the connection from localhost or over the network?

Comment: over the network

Comment: Are you sure Solr isn't just firewalled away? Does it work if you access it through localhost instead?

Comment: what do you mean? I just followed the instructions... I was able to install it on my other website ubuntu/apache, but not this time... I wonder if Nginx is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after

```
sudo ufw allow 8983
```

I can't believe all the online guides never mentioned it.